# Writing PolylineZ shapefile with pyshp

Tags: python, vector, 3d, pyshp

I am trying to write a POLYLINEZ file in Python with pyshp and find the documentation lacking... When importing a POLYLINEZ shapefile, the x,y values are separate from the z values. (`sf.shape().points` and `sf.shape().z`).
Do I need to separate them again when writing the shapefile? My data is currently in an array of x --- y --- z values.

In addition, what fields do I then need to create with `w.field`? Are the geometry fields created automatically or do I need to define them?

I really a beginner in coding... I understand that somehow I need to loop through the points(?) but I haven't been able to find an example of this loop online with Z values.

**EDIT:** Okay, I figured out that I can create a nested list and use w.linez...but why is it nested so many times? `[[[x,y,z]]]` What does the `w.record` then do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nesting reflects the structure of any Shapefile with "POLY" in the name. A POLYLINEZ shapefile type is made up of one or more parts. Each part is made up of two or more points as shown in the following diagram:

```
[ [ [x1,y1,z1],  [x2,y2,z2] ], [ [x3,y3,z3], [x4,y4,z4] ] ]
| | |            |             | |           |
| | |1st point   |2nd point    | |3rd Point  |4th Point
| |                            |
| |1st Part                    |2nd Part
|
|PolylineZ Geometry
```

Each one of the above geometry entries corresponds to a record. Think of the records as similar to a spreadsheet. The spreadsheet column names are called "fields". Each cell in a column is an attribute. Each row full of attributes is a record. The field() and record() functions define the column names and row values respectively. The geometry is not stored in the attributes unless you specifically create fields and attributes and store those values. You typically store information about what each line represents in the attribute, for example "NAME" for the name of a road or something.

Comment: So so helpful thank you! This is exactly what I needed.